# How do I add php ext-mailparse to an elastic beanstalk instance?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been unable to add the MailParse PHP extension (https://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse) to an instance of Elastic Beanstalk running PHP 7. My goal is to get it added into the boot sequence so that it's always installed when an instance is created.

My problem is that Amazon's version of Linux for EB doesn't offer PECL, so I am unsure how to get it loaded.

I've tried to adapt various approaches for installing other php extenions/modules, but haven't had any success.

https://packagist.org/packages/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser - I tried including this via my composer.json file, but it failed because "ext-mailparse" wasn't installed.

http://wiki.cerbweb.com/Installing_PHP_Mailparse_Ubuntu - I tried running these commands to install the extension, but the first command to install the dependencies failed.

https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-mailparse-extension.html - "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

I have a feeling there is an easier way to get this done but I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: Nope. I ended up parsing through the email using PlancakeEmailParser

Answer (score 0):

Create two files:

**.ebextensions/01mailparse.config**

```
commands:
  01install_mailparse:
    command: "pecl7 install --force mailparse"
```

Note the use of the `--force` flag. I added this since sometimes AWS EB automatically re-deploys the app in a way that PECL fails if it find the extension being already installed.

**.ebextensions/02prioritize.config**

```
commands:
  01change_mailparse_load_priority:
    command: "sed '/extension=\"mailparse.so\"/d' /etc/php.ini > /etc/php.ini && echo 'extension=\"mailparse.so\"' > /etc/php-7.0.d/zz_mailparse.ini"
```

This removes the mailparse extension registration from the `php.ini` file (PECL was adding the line at the top, weird) and registers it to be loaded at the end of the list (zz prefix).

Note that I used two files. For some reason, using two commands on the same file was making the deploy file. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

To add to `@Mauro`'s answer the following allows you to install mailparse and remove the extension from /etc/php.ini in a single file.

**.ebextensions/01_mailparse.config** (PHP 7.x)

```
commands:
    01_mailparse_install:
        command: |
            pecl7 install --force mailparse
            sed -i '/extension="mailparse.so"/d' /etc/php.ini

files:
    "/etc/php.d/mailparse.ini":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            extension="mailparse.so"
```

**.ebextensions/01_mailparse.config** (PHP 5.6)

```
commands:
    01_mailparse_install:
        command: |
            pecl install --force mailparse-2.1.6
            sed -i '/extension="mailparse.so"/d' /etc/php.ini

files:
    "/etc/php.d/mailparse.ini":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            extension="mailparse.so"
```

The `|` allows multi line values. I modified the `sed` command and added the files block to allow it to work on multiple PHP versions without much change.